Plot lines in folium with correct Mercator distortion
I’ve been looking around and not seen many answers / discussion about this, though maybe I am missing the right vocabulary.
I am using the Python Folium library to plot some lines and polygons over a map. For my use-case, I need the lines to be drawn along the earths curve, meaning they would show up as curved due to the Mercator projection.
Folium seems to only support straight lines and I haven’t been able to find any discussion about this issue, if anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.
My backup option was to treat each line independently (break the polygons up into lines), then draw each line as a bezier curve to achieve the needed distortion, however I have also not had luck identifying how to calculate Bezier control points based on the distortion caused by the Mercator projection.
Edit: It just occurred to me that my above suggestion of using a Bezier curve, while possible, is probably not the most efficient, instead it would probably be better to convert each point in the line / polygon into a x/y/z representation, calculate N points equally spaced between two points, then project those onto the globe and convert back to lon/lat.
Any advice / help would be greatly appreciated!

note that these are called "great circles", so if you weren't searching with that term, do another round of searching using that. Folium's own docs seem to suggest that you want a polyline here.

Good to know! Wasn’t aware of that term. Would like to clarify that just using a Folium PolyLine does not account for the issue mentioned in the post. A PolyLine plotted between two points will still be drawn as a straight line on the mercator projection rather than a curved one.

true, but that's why you sample it along the great circle between two points at a resolution good enough to look like a curve at the scale you're zoomed to.

Ended up chasing down the approach I mentioned in the Edit, seems to be fairly effective, I was able to get it working in the following script:
import folium
import pyproj
import itertools
import math

SAMPLE_COORDINATES = [[65.614249, -50.759657], [61.336557, 72.357013], [-29.119194, 80.783022], [-10.117030, -74.530119]]

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def render_coordinates(new_coords: list, old_coords: list):
    m = folium.Map(tiles="cartodb positron")

    bounds = compute_bounds(new_coords + old_coords)

    m.fit_bounds(bounds)

    folium.Polygon(
        locations=new_coords,
        color="red"
    ).add_to(m)

    folium.Polygon(
        locations=old_coords,
        color="blue"
    ).add_to(m)

    m.save("test.html")

def compute_bounds(coords: list):
    max_lat, max_lon = None, None
    min_lat, min_lon = None, None
    for (lat, lon) in coords:
        if min_lat is None or lat < min_lat:
            min_lat = lat
        if max_lat is None or lat > max_lat:
            max_lat = lat
        if min_lon is None or lat < min_lon:
            min_lon = lon
        if max_lon is None or lat > max_lon:
            max_lon = lon
    return ((min_lat, min_lon), (max_lat, max_lon))

def convert_LL_to_ECEF(ll_coords: list):
    transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(
        {"proj":'latlong', "ellps":'WGS84', "datum":'WGS84'},
        {"proj":'geocent', "ellps":'WGS84', "datum":'WGS84'},
    )
    ecef_coords = []
    for coords in ll_coords:
        x, y, z = transformer.transform(*(coords[::-1]), 0, radians=False)
        ecef_coords.append((x, y, z))
        
    return ecef_coords

def convert_ECEF_to_LL(ecef_coords: list):
    transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(
        {"proj":'geocent', "ellps":'WGS84', "datum":'WGS84'},
        {"proj":'latlong', "ellps":'WGS84', "datum":'WGS84'},
    )
    ll_coords = []
    for coords in ecef_coords:
        lon, lat, _ = transformer.transform(*coords, radians=False)
        ll_coords.append((lat, lon))

    return ll_coords

def compute_intermediary_points(ecef_coords: list, N: int):
    all_coords = []
    ecef_coords = ecef_coords + [ecef_coords[0]]
    for i, (coord_set_a, coord_set_b) in enumerate(pairwise(ecef_coords)):
        coord_set = []

        displacement = math.sqrt(
            (coord_set_a[0] - coord_set_b[0])**2 +
            (coord_set_a[1] - coord_set_b[1])**2 +
            (coord_set_a[2] - coord_set_b[2])**2)
            
        distanceBetweenPoints = displacement / (N + 1)

        for i in range(N):
            t = (distanceBetweenPoints * i) / displacement

            intermediate_coord = (
                    (1 - t) * coord_set_a[0] + t * coord_set_b[0],
                    (1 - t) * coord_set_a[1] + t * coord_set_b[1],
                    (1 - t) * coord_set_a[2] + t * coord_set_b[2]
            )

            coord_set.append(intermediate_coord)

        coord_set.append(coord_set_b)

        all_coords += coord_set

    return all_coords

def main():
    print("Processing coordinates.")

    ecef_coords = convert_LL_to_ECEF(SAMPLE_COORDINATES)

    new_coords = compute_intermediary_points(ecef_coords, 30)

    ll_coords = convert_ECEF_to_LL(new_coords)

    render_coordinates(ll_coords, SAMPLE_COORDINATES)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Its definitely not perfect, but does a decent job:

Hopefully someone else benefits from this!
